# React Nat Counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When clicking on a button, I want a value to increment by one each time. I want to call a function `incrementCounter()` to handle the operation for me, rather than: `onPress={() => this.setState({Count: ++this.state.Count})}`

This is my code so far for the class:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Count: 0,
    }
}
incrementCounter(){
    this.setState({
        Count: this.state.Count + 1 //!!! Where error occurs
    }); 
}

 render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{'Count: ' + this.state.Count} </Text>
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.incrementCounter}
                underlayColor='white'>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>+</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
 }
};
```

The code above results in an error - a red screen: 
"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.Count')" with the error on the line of the `incrementCounter()` <- Where comments show error occurs.

Most of the examples that I can find online are not using the ES6 syntax, however I want to try and stick to this to keep it standard across my application. The future work will include having a `decrementCounter()` function that will do the opposite, however will not allow the counter to drop below zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using the es6 notation, try the following:

```
 render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{'Count: ' + this.state.Count} </Text>
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.incrementCounter.bind(this)}
                underlayColor='white'>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>+</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
 }
```

Notice the .bind(this) on the event, this is needed so that it acutally references the class itself not some global function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly and have managed to implement for `decrementCounter` function too! Is there a good link for ES6 React Native functions?

Comment: Not that I really know of, however the guys at babel do have a great post about es6 + react, they also showed this issue with the bind,
http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/